# How to setup a Symfony website on a Microsoft Azure Web App?

Tags: php, azure, symfony, nginx

I build a PHP website with Symfony framework version 6.2 and running on PHP 8.2.
Via Github actions, I managed to deploy it to a Microsoft Azure Web App.

When I visit the default domain, created by the Microsoft Azure Web App, I see a "403 Forbidden, nginx/1.22.1" error message.

Via SSH, I can go to the created Azure Web App to check some settings.

My Symfony website is deployed to the folder `/home/site/wwwroot`.

This is the default `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 10068;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log off;
        error_log /dev/stderr;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

I'm pretty sure I need to change the `nginx.conf` configuration like explained in the Symfony documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

But I have no clue where I can add this extra configuration, because the `nginx.conf` file will be overwritten by every deploy.
Even when I manually change the configuration file, it doesn't work.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: There are several reasons why you are receving a 403 from Nginx. I'd recommend following this guide about setting up a PHP app in Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-php?tabs=cli&pivots=platform-linux

Comment: Hi @Luismi, I checked that page before but the deployment is totally different than the Hello World example. It's more about the configuration of my NGINX configuration files than the setup of a PHP website. Thanks for your help anyway! Really appreciated!

Comment: I see... You can persist your Symfony configuration using a startup.sh script on your container. Here is an example to setup a Wordpress site. Just use the symfony config instead of the WP provided: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/updating-nginx-default-configurations-on-azure-app-services/ba-p/3710146

Then, to persist changes on container boot, follow this guide: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-run-bash-scripts-in-wordpress-on-azure-app-service/ba-p/3625692

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re thought process is correct, though you’re looking at the wrong configuration file. The file that should be modified is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

For your second issue, where the settings are being overwritten, the solution is to use the command line instruction.

```
cp nginx.default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default && service nginx restart
```

I have a full article about it on https://www.azurephp.dev/2021/09/php-8-on-azure-app-service/ if you want to learn more.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I have changed the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` with the lines `listen 80;` and `root /home/site/wwwroot/public;`. Now I get 502 bad gateway error.
When I change listen to port 8080 (like the default configuration) I get a 404 not found error. What should be the problem now? Is it my PHP (or PHP-FPM) that is on a different port? Or how can I check this?

Comment: Make sure that nginx is restarted (not the app service)

Also make sure that you have the following configuration

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    )

This was my nemesis when setting up the new app service.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DragonBe, I found out that I had to change my nginx configuration in the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

I created a file `/home/site/wwwroot/nginx.default` in the root of my Symfony project:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
            fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
            fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

After the deploy with Github Actions, I run this command:

```
cp /home/site/wwwroot/nginx.default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default && service nginx restart
```

I hope this will help other Symfony websites with their deployment to an Azure Web App.